# Декодировать элементы массива из JSON

Tags: php

Есть массив:

```
$arr = [
       [0] => [
              [date_time] => 2018-05-14 00:54:27,
              [total] => 545,
              [string] => {"21":{"price":"30.28","title":"Some text"},"76":{"price":"533.44","title":"Some text2"}}
              ],
        [1] => [
              [date_time] => 2018-05-14 00:30:27,
              [total] => 5435,
              [string] => {"26":{"price":"100.28","title":"Some text"},"72":{"price":"5354.44","title":"Some text2"}}
              ],
         [2] => [
              [date_time] => 2018-05-14 12:30:27,
              [total] => 43,
              [string] => {"18":{"price":"143.28","title":"Some text"},"98":{"price":"5354.44","title":"Some text2"}}
              ],
        ];
```

Как мне пробежаться по массиву и декодировать JSON? Я знаю, что нужно применить `json_decode($arr, true)`, но не получается это сделать в цикле...

Мой неработающий код:

```
       foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $last = array_pop($value);
            $lastOk = json_decode($last, true);
            array_push($value, $lastOk);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        $dec = json_decode($arr[$key]['string'], true);
        $arr[$key]['string'] = $dec;
}
```

Вот так должно работать.

Comment: что-то не получается, всё равно в  JSON остается

Comment: @KvinT исправил ответ.

Comment: я додумался JSON добавить, не помогает...

Comment: @KvinT исправил.

Comment: работает, сэнкс за помощь